# Matlab - How to concat dataset name + i in for loop?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, dataset

I have a dataset containing several arrays which are identified by a generic name and a number. I would like to modify arrays independently from each other in a for loop like so:

```
for i=1:length(dataset)
 dataset.GenericName_i(row,column)=f(x)
end
```

Do you know a way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood that looks like dynamic field [referencing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/).

You could do it like so (using `k` instead of `i` as a loop counter...try to avoid using either `i` or `j` for that purpose):

```
for k=1:length(dataset)

   Name = sprintf('GenericName_%i',k);

   %// Note the use of brackets to create a dynamic field
   dataset.(Name) =f(x);

end
```

Is that what you meant?

Comment: That's how I would interpret the question too. +1.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I meant, sorry for the vague question. I had tried with different versions of 'num2str' but of course it hadn't done the trick. Thanks!